# Creating variable in ModelBuilder specifying range of possible values?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.3

In the ModelBuilder (ArcGIS 10.3) I'm creating a tool where I want to let the user decide the `Percentage_Of_Overlap`, which is a field in my vector dataset.

For that, I want to create a variable where the user can insert a integer between 0 and 100.

I'm using the Selecting Tool, so it would be (in the Query Builder):

```
PercentageOfOverlap >= Value
```

Where the `Value`, will be the inserted value by the user.

How to do that with ModelBuilder?

Comment: What does this part of your model look like at the moment?  Please include a picture to illustrate what you have tried.  When you say "Selecting Tool", do you mean the Select (Analysis) tool?

Answer (score 2):

You want to be creating a [standalone variable](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/creating-stand-alone-variables.htm) (what you are calling Value) then expose it as a [parameter](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/exposing-tool-parameters-as-variables.htm). You could then set a [Range Filter](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/range-filter.htm) of 0 to 100.

Would recommend you spend some quality time looking into the model builder section of the Help file as this give examples and walkthroughs.